Equivalence of Kraus operators on a single element
Let's say that I'm working in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$,suppose I have two bounded operators $A.B\in B(\mathcal{H})$ and a positive semidefinite operator $x$, for example take $x$ to be a density matrix, that is $\operatorname{tr}(x)=1,x=x^*,x\geq 0$.
Suppose then that $x$ has support $S$.\
If we have that $AxA^*=BxB^*$ what can I say about $A$ and $B$? Intuitively I would say that when resctricted on acting on $S$ they are equal, but this is of course false because I could take for example $A=-B$. On the other hand since $x=\sum_{k}p_kP_kP_k^*$, they must be somehow related.

If $x$ is trace class, then I think that the condition $\operatorname{tr}(x[A^A - B^B]) = 0$ is equivalent to $AxA^ = BxB^$

I suspect that, in general, $AxA^* = BxB^*$ holds if and only if there exists a unitary operator $U$ such that $A|_S = UB|_S$.

I agree, but maybe unitarily similar is too much, technically if you had an isometry it would still work. On the other hand since they are equal I feel like there are infinite many other conditions that are not being used: $\operatorname{tr}((AxA^)^m)=\operatorname{tr}((BxB^)^m)$

This is not unitary similarity. Unitary similarity would mean that $A = UBU^*$. But yes, the $U$ in my equation could merely be an isometry rather than a unitary operator.

Also, I agree with your comment regarding the trace. For some reason I was thinking about the case where $A^*A - B^*B$ is positive semidefinite, which we have no reason to presume. The trace condition is necessary but not sufficient.

Notable fact:
$$
AxA^* = BxB^* \iff
[Ax^{1/2}][Ax^{1/2}]^* = [Bx^{1/2}][Bx^{1/2}]^*
$$

$\def\ran{\operatorname{ran}}$
Lemma. Let $S,T\in B(H)$. Then $S^*S=T^*T$ if and only if there exists a partial isometry $V:\overline\ran T\to\overline\ran S$ with $S=VT$.
If $AxA^*=BxB^*$, you can apply the Lemma to $x^{1/2}A^*$ and $x^{1/2}B^*$; so there exists a partial isometry $V:\overline{\ran}x^{1/2}A^*\to\overline{\ran}x^{1/2}B^*$ with $x^{1/2}B^*=Vx^{1/2}A^*$. We can write this as $Ax^{1/2}V^*=Bx^{1/2}$. I don't think one can get a lot more than this, for $x$ can take many different forms.

Proof of the Lemma. Suppose first that $S^*S=T^*T$. Define $V:\ran T\to\ran S$ by $V(T\xi)=S\xi$. This is well defined and is in fact an isometry, for
$$
\|S\xi\|^2=\langle S^*S\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle T^*T\xi,\xi\rangle=\|T\xi\|^2. 
$$
Being bounded, $V$ admits a unique extension to $\overline\ran T$, and we can extend is as zero on $(\ran T)^\perp=\ker T^*$.
Conversely, suppose that $V$ is a partial isometry $\overline\ran T\to\overline\ran S$. Then $V^*V$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\overline\ran T$. Thus $S^*S=T^*V^*VT=T^*T$.

If $S=TV$ then $T^S=V$ and $T^$ is a coisometry. Applying the lemma the other way round I get $T=KS$ with $K$ isometry. Is there an "either or" or is it a problem of uniqueness?

I'm sorry, I don't follow. Why would $S=TV$ imply $T^*S=V$ when $T$ is not a unitary?

I'm sorry I've messed up your notation and inverted V and T. What I wanted to say is that if there exists a (partial) isometry $V$ ,such that $S=VT$. Since $V$ is an isometry then $V^*V=\mathbb{I}$. Thus $V^*S=V^*VT=T$. On the other hand using that lemma the other way round there exists $K$ isometry such that $KS=T$. Thus we have $T=V^*S=KS$. I wrote that there may be an "either or" because if the map that connects $T$ and $S$ is unique there might be some problem

Still not sure what you are aiming for. The lemma doesn't mention uniqueness, and $V$ is a partial isometry, not necessarily an isometry. The partial isometry $V$ is unique if $T$ (and hence $S$) has dense range. Other than that the lemma tells you nothing about what $V$ does on $\ker T^*$.
